# Asking for Special Treatment/ Annoying Professors

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am thinking about suggesting to a professor I do security work or an RAship for a Graduate Assistantship (if I am accepted). However I know their use for graduate students is to grade papers and similar tasks. Is this kind of Hail Mary attempt bad? There is a big potential reward (spending 20 more hours thinking and not exerting mental energy on other kinds of tasks). But the negative is that if they mark me as annoying I might not be able to get as much from them going forward. Is this kind of "life hack" attempt not as worth it in an academic environment? This is the only program I am applying to, although I am willing to do a menial job for a year if it means I get more time to think.

What complicates the situation is that this is my department from undergrad. While my main recomenders are pure math folk in the department (which I will need later too), these people are the statistics faculty (and its a stats program). Thus I will only need something from them if I do some nice theoretical stuff during the program, which I would think would make the early annoyance moot.

Comment: I had a hard time trying to understand what you're asking. Neither the context nor the question are explained clearly. Could you please reword your text to make it understandable to a wider audience? As an aside, recall that whatever you're going to ask to a professor, you would sound less annoying if you write in a clear and concise way, using paragraphs.

Comment: This question reads like the output from a random text generator.

Comment: I guess, my not being Wittgenstein, I should do the hard work of thinking.

Comment: Yes, a bit incoherent... Practicing coherence is a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

GRAs aren't long-shot attempts. Either the professor has some source of funding to offer a GRA or they don't. If they do, you can apply and see if you are hired to work with the professor, so asking them is one way to find out if such a job exists (looking at their website is often another good one). Sometimes departments admit additional students and offer them TAships where they are expected to grade, teach recitation/discussion sessions, etc.

Asking a professor if they have a position open isn't annoying and it isn't a life hack. The only real way to know if such a position is available is to ask. You don't want to be annoying by asking them repeatedly, begging, not taking no for an answer, etc, but telling someone you know that you're going to apply to grad school in their department and would like to work with them is exactly how this gets done.

Comment: But what if you know these positions don't "exist" and that you are trying to get a job that doesn't exist? I know this is common in the private sector but seems unusual to me in this circumstance.

Comment: Why put "exist" in scare quotes? What are you trying to imply? Your best bet is to approach the prof you want to work with, let them know that you plan to apply, tell them that you'd like to work with them if you're accepted, and ask them what you should do.

Comment: Philosophical reasons that are tangential to the discussion. I don't know about current maths so I don't have professors I "want to work with" :( although i will try to work with the professors at the school nonetheless.

Comment: @123, if you don't know anything about what you want to work on on who you want to work with, then it's too soon to ask for a GRA for your PhD. It might even be too soon to be thinking of applying for a PhD program. You don't need to know your thesis topic before your apply, but you probably need to know if your interests lie more towards geometry, analysis, or number theory (or whatever). If you at least have an area in mind, then you ought to be talking to professors you like in that area about undergraduate research opportunities.